# Windows Movie Maker cannot open my .wlmp project saying it's corrupted

Tags: video-editing

How to fix a corrupted .wlmp (Windows Movie Maker project) file? I had some problem when working on the file; Movie Maker said something went bad and asked if I want to save the file; I chose "save". Now when I try to open the file, Movie Maker says it's "corrupted". What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, [the following answer from "considerate_guy" at answers.microsoft.com helped me fix a corrupt .wlmp file](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/moviemaker-files/help-with-corrupted-wlmp-file/40d46f3e-4379-4463-aa49-aae568927463):

> [...] If you want to try fixing the problem yourself, make a *copy* of the project file. Right-click on the project file and choose "Open with..." and pick Notepad. (However, don't make that the default file association or all future projects will try to launch Notepad rather than Movie Maker).
>
> Now manually find each instance of outTime and check the value. If it is 0 or earlier than the inTime, change it to be equal to the length of the original clip. You can find the length of each media item listed at the top of the file.

Summarizing in nice bullet points:

1. Make a **copy** of the project file.
2. **Right-click** the project file, choose **"Open with..."** and pick **Notepad**. (However, don't make that the default file association, or all future projects will try to launch Notepad rather than Movie Maker.)
3. Find each instance of **`outTime`** and check the value. If it is **`"0"`** or **earlier (smaller) than `inTime`**, change it to be equal to the length of the original clip.

   - You can find the length of the original clip by checking the `mediaItemID` number in row with corrupted `outTime`; then find a `MediaItem` with the same `id` at the top of the file, and take the `duration` value.